# Entity Framework 4 Error: Unable to update the EntitySet because it has a DefiningQuery

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Okay, here's the scenario.  I have 3 tables.  One called aspnet_Users one called Categories and a linking table called User_Categories.  aspnet_Users and Categories both have primary keys (UserId and ID respectively).  The linking table has only two columns: CategoryID and UserId, and there are foreign key relationships setup for each column AND I have a unique key setup for the two columns on User_Categories.  This sets up a many-to-many relationship between the aspnet_Users table and the Categories table.  I generated my entities edmx file from this database setup, and everything looks perfect and works for almost all operations.

What I want to do is add a new category from a form (which works perfecly by itself), and also, at the same time, associate a specific user with that newly submitted category.  When I try to do this I get the error in my subject line.  Here is the code I'm using to try this (ctx is my entities context object):

```
public ActionResult Create(Category category, Guid userId)
{
    aspnet_Users user = ctx.aspnet_Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserId == userId);
    ctx.Categories.AddObject(category);
    user.Categories.Add(category);
    ctx.SaveChanges();;
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 39):

I assume the full exception message is something similar to:

> Unable to update the EntitySet *YourTableName* because it has a DefiningQuery and no InsertFunction element exists in the ModificationFunctionMapping element to support the current operation.

This will occur if your DB's table doesn't have a primary key defined.

Add a primary key to your table (using SQL Server Management Studio or whatever), and update your `.edmx` model from the database.

Comment: what happen if you get this on a View instead of a Table!!

Comment: @Necronet, sorry I can't say.  Views can define keys too, right?  Do you have one defined on your view?

Comment: yes but EF seems to be setting my keys automaticly (and randomly too), i tried to edit the dmx with XML editor but every time i update it sets the key right back, dont know why...

Comment: Not supposed to have primary key on a FK mapping many-to-many table.

Answer (score 2):

Error: Unable to update the EntitySet because it has a DefiningQuery

Twice I got this error, twice I searched for answers everywhere, and in the end my mappings was messed up or the database had no primary key or something. I suggest checking it all out...

Answer (score 2):

I encounter the same problem, and I fixed by the following link:

- [Link @ Microsoft social forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/94db7213-a245-4282-86c6-2399eac33229)
- [Link @ StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589166/it-has-a-definingquery-but-no-insertfunction-element-err)
- [Link @ Blog of Microsoft](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/09/01/tip-34-how-to-work-with-updatable-views.aspx)

I remove the section of *DefiningQuery* in .edmx based on the content of 3rd link. And then everything works as a charm.

Comment: This isn't sustainable in a database first model. Updating the model will blow away the changes.

Answer (score 2):

Put a composite primary key on the mapping table, this will tell EF to handle it correctly.