# i have created scaffolding in MVC. After filling data in the form when I click on create button, below error occurs

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is the error i get when I'm trying to save data to my table.

Error:

> An exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to update the `EntitySet`
>   '`CustormerD`' because it has a `DefiningQuery` and no
>   `<InsertFunction>` element exists in the
>   `<ModificationFunctionMapping>` element to support the current
>   operation.

Controller Code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="custid,name,cell_No,address,date,time,serviceNo")] CustormerD custormerd)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.CustormerDs.Add(custormerd);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(custormerd);
}
```

table code below:

```
public partial class CustormerD
{
    public int custid { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> cell_No { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> date { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.TimeSpan> time { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> serviceNo { get; set; }
}
```

**sql code**

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustormerD](
[custid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[name] [nchar](20) NULL,
[cell_No] [int] NULL,
[address] [nchar](20) NULL,
[date] [date] NULL,
[time] [time](7) NULL,
[serviceNo] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: This error may be occurred , if your table doesn't have primary key!

Comment: Add`[Key]` on `custid`

Comment: can you please assist me where im failing in my database table

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustormerD](
 [custid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 
            ) ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: Have you added `[key]`?

Comment: check the line i just added

Comment: I can not see anywhere, where you added?

Comment: Are you using code first, right? so do not need to change at database side just make change on your entity class: Add `[key]` on above `public int custid { get; set; }`

Comment: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'KeyAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) after i ve add key on my entity class

Comment: you have to referenced `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`

Comment: still not working

Comment: *still not working* can do explain because here you've two issue first is get an error as per question and  *name 'KeyAttribute' could not be found*

Comment: directive is working thanx on that one and still not saving

Comment: Did you get an error, which you get before?

Comment: yes still the same

Comment: are you using code first or edmx?

Comment: Edmx not code first

Comment: update your .edmx model from the database. you've already added key over there

Comment: doesnot alow me too

Comment: *doesnot alow me too* what error you get now?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3654184/4753489

Comment: property value not valid

Comment: Here seems like your primary key not set using upper script, so run answered script

Comment: Div thanx for time now its working problem was to set the primary key on sql server on my table.

Comment: Yes, I've added right script in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per discussed in comment OP use `.edmx`file.

So you can set primary key to your table like following:

```
USE [yourdatbase]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[CustormerD]    Script Date: 26/09/2016 4:08:23 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustormerD](
    [custid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [nchar](20) NULL,
    [cell_No] [int] NULL,
    [address] [nchar](20) NULL,
    [date] [date] NULL,
    [time] [time](7) NULL,
    [serviceNo] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CustormerD] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [custid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

After set the primary key, you should update your `.edmx` model from the database.

Answer (score 0):

The Entity Framework will only assume a primary key from your model if the name of the field is the name of the model + ID.  Otherwise you will have to explicitly state which field to use as a primary key.  For your model that would mean either changing the name of your primary key to:

```
public int CustomerDID { get; set; }
```

Entity framework would then automatically assume it as the primary key.  Alternatively you label your primary key using [Key] as follows:

```
    public partial class CustormerD
{
    [Key]
    public int custid { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> cell_No { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> date { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.TimeSpan> time { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> serviceNo { get; set; }
}
```