# Entity FrameWork - Exception on SaveChanges

Tags: entity-framework, savechanges

I have this code saving a simple  Entity:

```
ExecutionEngineEntities db = new ExecutionEngineEntities();
Task task = new Task();
task.Message = "Test";
task.Result = "Test";
task.Name = "Test";
db.Tasks.AddObject(task);
db.SaveChanges();
```

This is the exception:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.UpdateException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll
Unable to update the EntitySet 'Tasks' because it has a DefiningQuery and no <InsertFunction> element exists in the <ModificationFunctionMapping> element to support the current operation.
The program '[6092] WebDev.WebServer40.EXE: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

This is the create table code:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tasks](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nchar](50) NULL,
    [Message] [nchar](1000) NULL,
    [Result] [nchar](1000) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**After searching in google I found that mode people who got this error has a relation problems, this is not my case**

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the answer here can help you: [It has a DefiningQuery but no InsertFunction element... err](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589166/it-has-a-definingquery-but-no-insertfunction-element-err)

It could be that in the EF model it is configured that this entity is a view and not a table. Views don't support create, update or delete operations, so you can't insert.

Comment: Thanks, the answer helped me,  but I have created a table not a view.... What went wrong, how do i make EF to see it as an table and not a view?

Comment: In the answer that I have linked there is another link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/09/01/tip-34-how-to-work-with-updatable-views.aspx which tells you how to check if it's configured as a table or a view in the model