# Can't save data to database in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I want to save data to my database after a user registered. I wrote code in Registerfunctin in Account controller. the code is:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Attempt to register the user
                MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
                Membership.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email, null, null, true, null, out createStatus);

                if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);
                    ///My code for saving in dtabase
                            Recommend ad = new Recommend();      
                            ad.estate = 1;
                            ad.industry = 1;
                            storedb.AddToRecommends(ad);         
                            storedb.SaveChanges();
                    ///
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
                }
            }


            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

Recommend is the name of table that I want to store 1 in estate and industry column. I used this way for saving befor in another controller and everything were OK, But now I get this exception:

[image: Exception]

Can anybody tells me whats the problem? 
Thanks alot

Comment: Are you using StoredProcedure to handle the Add and Update for this Recommend table ??

Comment: can you paste here the details in the "Copy exception details to the clipboard"? This info is usually much more helpful. Also can you paste a picture of your table design?

Answer (score 2):

The exception is pretty clear what the problem is: The EntitySet `Recommend` and the type `Recommend` is defined by a [**Defining Query**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738450.aspx). That means it is the result of a SQL query specified in the store schema of the EDMX file. This is similar to mapping a view from the database, i.e. it is read-only and you can't update it, can't insert data into the set and you can't delete data from it.

It is possible though to [**map Stored Procedures**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716711.aspx) to the Insert, Update, Delete operations of the entity defined by a Defining Query, but the exception also says that no procedure is specified to support the Insert operation.

You are talking about a `Recommend` *table*, so the question is why the `Recommend` set isn't directly mapped to this table. As far as I know a Defining Query must be written manually by a developer and put into the EDMX file manually. The "Update model from database" does not create a Defining Query. Who wrote this query? How did you create the EDMX file at all? Database-First or Model-First or hand-written XML or...?

**Edit**

The last paragraph in my answer above is not correct. It's *possible* that a developer could have written a Defining Query manually, but when you use Database-First approach (which I assume) much more *likely* is that your table in the database does not have a primary key. In that case [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1589406/270591) applies:

> Well when a table is encountered without a PrimaryKey it is treated as
>   a View.
>
> And views show up in the EDMX file (open in an XML editor to see) in
>   the **StorageModel\EntitySet[n]\DefiningQuery** element.

Solution: Check in the database if your `Recommend` table has a primary key. If it doesn't have a key, add one.