# How to write Entity Framework when the table has foreign key

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework

Tables `t1 {id, name, addr_id}` and `t2 {addr_id, addr}`

When you create entity for `t1` like

```
dim db = new t1entity()
dim tt = from t in db.t1s where t.addr_id
```

Here, I cannot use `addr_id` corresponding to the t

Comment: There is a link that might help you. 

Check here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589166/it-has-a-definingquery-but-no-insertfunction-element-err[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589166/it-has-a-definingquery-but-no-insertfunction-element-err

Answer (score 0):

If you have navigation properties correctly set, you can use where `t.t2.addr_id`. If you are using .NET 4.0 or newer [you can tell EF to generate `addr_id` property directly](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/11/06/foreign-key-relationships-in-the-entity-framework.aspx) in `t1` entity. That will use [FK association instead of independent association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281974/code-first-independent-associations-vs-foreign-key-associations/5282275#5282275) you are using at the moment.